# Script to write .csv using cron job produces empty cells

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi-zero, speed-test

## Background

I am using a raspberrypi zero to test the internet speed with the `speedtest --csv` command.

I have written a script that is placed in `/usr/local/bin/speedtest_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the file path for storing results
FILE_PATH="/home/marko/speedtest/speedtest_raspberrypi.csv"

# Run the speedtest and capture the results
SPEEDTEST_RESULT=$(speedtest --csv)

# Check if the CSV file exists; if not, create the header
if [ ! -f "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
   echo "Date,Time,Ping (ms),Download,Upload,Location,Distance" > "$FILE_PATH"
fi

# Extract and format the data from the `speedtest` output
DATE=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
TIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
PING=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $6}')
DOWNLOAD=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $7}')
UPLOAD=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $8}')
LOCATION=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')
DISTANCE=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $5}')

# Append the formatted results to the CSV file
echo "$DATE,$TIME,$PING,$DOWNLOAD,$UPLOAD,$LOCATION,$DISTANCE" >> "$FILE_PATH"
```

The file `speedtest_script.sh` has been made into an executable using the commands `sudo chmod +x speedtest_script.sh` and `sudo chmod +w speedtest_script.sh` to give it read and write permissions.

## My Problem

With this background, here is the problem I am facing:

As seen in the code, the script is supposed to generate a file `speedtest_raspberrypi.csv` in `/home/marko/speedtest/speedtest_raspberrypi.csv`. When I manually run the command `speedtest_script.sh`, it executes perfectly. However, as part of a cron job, I only get the date and time, but not the other relevant information.

A snippet of the speedtest_raspberrypi.csv is given below:

```
Date,Time,Ping (ms),Download,Upload,Location,Distance
2023/10/29,14:35:10,28.941,33661436.554366775,12456063.667141322,MyCity,196.5378436042561
2023/10/29,14:45:02,,,,,
```

The first line of results was generated when I manually executed the command.
The second line of results was generated as part of the cron job.

Here is what I have written in my `crontab -e`:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/15 * * * * speedtest_script.sh
```

## Question

Why does my script generate the correct output when run manually, but not when part of a cronjob?

Comment: Guessing without testing. The speedtest binary is not accessible by the Cron. Run which speedtest and replace the script with the full path returned by which

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you have a misconception -

`sudo chmod +w speedtest_script.sh` doesn't give the script read and write permissions. Rather it gives write permission *on that file* for all categories of users. This means that after the command is executed, *any user* will be able to modify the `speedtest_script.sh` script itself.

i.e. rather than giving "read and write permissions" *to it*, you are giving users write permissions *on it*.

Secondly, to answer your question "Why does my script generate the correct output when run manually, but not when part of a cronjob?" - I would guess your issue is that cron jobs do not have the same `PATH` environment variable as the user. So if `speedtest` is not found in the default `PATH` that the cron job has, it will fail to execute the command. Hence you not seeing any data.

To fix this just ensure your script has the correct path to `speedtest` explicitly set. e.g.

run the command

`which speedtest`

It should output something like `/usr/bin/speedtest`

Then just use that absolute path in your script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the file path for storing results
FILE_PATH="/home/marko/speedtest/speedtest_raspberrypi.csv"

# Run the speedtest and capture the results using the absolute path
# for example...
SPEEDTEST_RESULT=$(/usr/bin/speedtest --csv)

# Check if the CSV file exists; if not, create the header
if [ ! -f "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
   echo "Date,Time,Ping (ms),Download,Upload,Location,Distance" > "$FILE_PATH"
fi

# Extract and format the data from the `speedtest` output
DATE=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
TIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
PING=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $6}')
DOWNLOAD=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $7}')
UPLOAD=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $8}')
LOCATION=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')
DISTANCE=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $5}')

# Append the formatted results to the CSV file
echo "$DATE,$TIME,$PING,$DOWNLOAD,$UPLOAD,$LOCATION,$DISTANCE" >> "$FILE_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

A general recommendation for testing errors in scripts where you can't directly access STDERR (such as when it's run via crontab): append  `2>> /tmp/stderr.log` (or a similar log location) to any lines that you think might be producing errors.  Then after the crontab has run, you can go back and review `/tmp/stderr.log` to see what errors were generated.

For example, you might modify your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the file path for storing results
FILE_PATH="/home/marko/speedtest/speedtest_raspberrypi.csv"

# Run the speedtest and capture the results
SPEEDTEST_RESULT=$(speedtest --csv 2>> /tmp/stderr.log)

# Check if the CSV file exists; if not, create the header
if [ ! -f "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
   echo "Date,Time,Ping (ms),Download,Upload,Location,Distance" > "$FILE_PATH"
fi

# Extract and format the data from the `speedtest` output
DATE=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
TIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
PING=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $6}')
DOWNLOAD=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $7}')
UPLOAD=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $8}')
LOCATION=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')
DISTANCE=$(echo "$SPEEDTEST_RESULT" | awk -F ',' '{print $5}')

# Append the formatted results to the CSV file
echo "$DATE,$TIME,$PING,$DOWNLOAD,$UPLOAD,$LOCATION,$DISTANCE" >> "$FILE_PATH"
```

I suspect that the error is likely that you need the absolute path of `speedtest` (as @Fraser mentioned), but if the error is due to something else this method will also help you troubleshoot (and is useful in general).